# How to dynamically change a Field's Type in SilverStripe

Tags: php, forms, object, field, silverstripe

I'm trying to change a field's type dynamically based on a few conditions in SilverStripe.

I have a Field e.g. `CheckboxField()` which i need to copy and change the type of to something else e.g. `DropdownField()` or any other type of field.

Is there a way to do this before the object is pushed to the form and whats the best practice here?

Comment: Is this for the backend SilverStripe CMS (aka. `getCMSFields`) or something else? It should be as simple as `removeByName` of the `CheckboxField` and then `addFieldToTab` (or `push`) your new field of whatever you want. If it is `getCMSFields`, can you show us what you currently have so we can create an answer tailored to your question?

Comment: Also when you get back to my previous question, how are you intending on storing the different data? I'm going to assume your intention is to store the data as different DB or `has_one` properties? Just provide us with a little more information :)

Comment: @Turnerj it's for a frontend userform...form. I'm creating a custom field that can be change into any other type of field but i wasn't sure how to do this part correctly.

Comment: I'm currently just using a conditional statement to switch - https://github.com/mediabeastnz/campaign-monitor-userform/blob/master/code/extensions/EditableCampaignMonitorField.php#L114

Comment: AHHHH, `CheckboxSetField`, not a `CheckboxField`! I guess you really have a solution to your question already then about how to do it, your real question is just what is the best method to do it? That code you linked to is one of the more optimised ways of doing it, I would probably implement it similarly. If that is your code, it is a pretty good way of doing it.

Comment: Yeah sorry at the time of writing the question i was experimenting on how to do it. Ok that's good to know i headed in the right direction.
I'll leave leave the answer open incase there is a correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **replaceField** http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-FieldList.html#_replaceField

```
function getCMSFields() {
  $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
  $fields->replaceField('MyField', DropdownField::create('MyField', 'My field'));
  return $fields;
}
```

Comment: One problem with that is that a `CheckboxField` fundamentally stores different data than a `DropdownField`. It is likely he will need to use a different DB property. So while he can still leverage the `replaceField` function, he will probably need a different name for the `DropdownField`.

Comment: You might be better of using display logic https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-display-logic  You can hide and show fields depending on certain conditions such as if a checkbox is checked, then you could display the dropdown field.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a condition in getCMSField

```
function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
    $source = SomeDataObject::get();
    $fields->removeByName('MyField');
    if($source->count() > 1) {
        $fields->addFieldToTab('MyTab', DropdownField::create('MyField', 'My field', $source->map()->toArray()));
    } else {
        $fields->addFieldToTab('MyTab', CheckboxField::create('MyField', 'My field', $source->first()->Name));
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: While that is a potential solution, if this is for a `DataObject` in `ModelAdmin`, the field would actually already exist due to scaffolding so your example would add the field a second time. Also as I mentioned on the other answer, it has a fundamental storage flaw that a `DropdownField` stores different data than a `CheckboxField`. Your CheckboxField converts values to `0` or `1`, so even passing the first name from the source list, that won't store as intended in the `MyField` property.

Comment: Im currently doing it this way (see my link above) but not sure if this is the best practice way to do it?

Comment: @Turnerj You can remove the field with `removeByName` before the condition. `DropdownField` does not stores any data, it's not a `DBField` but rather a `FormField`. `MyField` could subclass `TextField` and be used to save the value selected from either the dropdown or the checkbox. You could even use the function `onBeforeWrite` to manipulate the value before writing in the db.

Comment: @cbarberis, I know that you can remove the field, I just mentioned it as your original post didn't factor that in. For `getCMSFields` to automatically save, `MyField` needs to be a DB property or a `has_one` relationship for `Form::saveInto` to work. While you could subclass a `DBField` to handle the value from both field types, there would be issues like when saving a checked checkbox, the value you would be provided would be 1, potentially the same value as a DB object's ID and you won't know what field type was used.

Comment: @cbarberis (cont.) While you may get around that issue, it isn't how it is handled out-of-the-box so anyone looking at this answer may get the wrong impression. Our few comments back and forth are the only thing that describes the potential issue to any visitors. I guess just make a note of it of it in your answer.

Comment: @Turnerj I'm not talking about subclassing `DBField`, and yes you are right my approach requires a bit of work on top of the out-of-the-box functionality, but using `onBeforeWrite` is quite basic once you start using SilverStripe CMS. @Myles let me know if you need further help with it. Just remember, DB fields and Form fields must match if you want `getCMSField` to save their values automatically, but nothing stops you from programmatically altering values before storing them in the db.